# Perl identifying md5 hash and printing it

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have problem with my simple perl script:

```
open IN, "<file1.txt" or die print "can't open file!";

while($line = <IN>){
    $line =~ /[a-z0-9]{32}/i;
    my $substr = $1;
    print $substr;
}
```

it has to identify md5 hashes in file, one per line, and print it, but it is not working properly, it prints me nothing, or if I modify something it gives me output

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

I have no clue what's wrong with it.

Comment: `if I modify something it gives me output` what are you modifying?

Comment: @Braj I tried to make some changes in code, nevermind, it works now :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't capturing anything using parenthesis.

Also, it is wise to check to see if a regex actually matches before trying to use the captured groups.

```
if ($line =~ /([a-z0-9]{32})/i) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```